# How to run different pytest commands on windows vs Linux with Tox?

Tags: python, pytest, tox

I figured the following would work but only if I pass `tox -e linux` or `tox -e win32` are any tests ran at all.

```ini
[testenv]
commands =
  linux: py.test {posargs}
  win32: py.test -m "not fails_on_windows" {posargs}

deps =
  pyflakes
  pytest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[tox]
envlist = py39-{linux,mac,win}

[testenv]
platform =
    linux: linux
    mac: darwin
    win: win32
commands =
  linux: py.test {posargs}
  win: py.test -m "not fails_on_windows" {posargs}
deps =
  pyflakes
  pytest
```

Here we create an `envlist` for Python 3.9 that includes the platforms Mac, Windows32 and Linux. These can then use the env specific commands. The documentation for platform specification on tox is [here](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/faq.html#platform-specification) with included examples.